# Scribbleton doesn't run on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, error-handling

I am trying to install and run [Scribbleton](https://scribbleton.com/) on `Linux Mint 19`, but when I do `./run_scribbleton.sh` nothing happens.

Talking to the support, they asked me to modify the `run_scribbleton.sh` script to print out any errors, so this is what I have done:

```
[uncommented]$dirname/bin/Scribbleton "$@"

[commented]$dirname/bin/Scribbleton "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Now when I ran `./run_scribbleton.sh`, the following message appeared:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

The support managed to reproduce the issue on `Mint 19`, but not to fix it. He said that this is a Mint relevant issue, because he was able to run `Scribbleton` on many `Linux distributions`, including `Ubuntu`.

Would you please provide any clarification about this issue?

Comment: Possible 64bit code on 32bit kernel.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 19 64bit and the software is 64bit as well. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You have a [solved] solution, what happened?https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=276553